# Comes first or before something

Tags: word-usage, usage

I'm talking to someone about our roll numbers. My roll number is 23 and her roll number is 30.

So what's the best way to describe it:

> My roll number comes first.
>
> My roll number comes before yours.

And if I'm telling my little sister about a number or a letter:

> C comes first. (When she asks me "What comes first C or D?"
>
> C comes before D.

And:

> 45 comes first.
>
> 45 comes before 46.

What's preferred?

Answer (score 1):

Either way is correct. It's really just a matter of preference.

To me, it sounds better to say

> X comes first.

because it doesn't mention the other option, and might be a bit more emphasizing. But then again, it's a matter of preference.